# Transferring proceeds from sale of inherited apartment from Russia to the US

Tags: united-states, money-transfer, inheritance, russia, sanctions

My adult children will inherit an apartment in Saint Petersburg, Russia. After the complexities of selling, taxes, and so forth, will there be any problem with a bank transferring the proceeds — the amount will be between $100-200K — to the US? Will US sanctions on Russia affect it at all?